# Page files size from CSV

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I've got the following script, that checks the page file size on a remote server, is it possible to run this against a CSV file of hostnames?

```
clear 

$strComputer="computername"

$PageFile=Get-WmiObject Win32_PageFile -ComputerName $strComputer 
Write-Host "Page File Size in MB: " ($PageFile.Filesize/(1024*1024))

$colItems=Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -Namespace root\CIMv2 -ComputerName $strComputer 
$total=0 
foreach ($objItem in $colItems) {
    $total=$total+ $objItem.Capacity 
}

$isPAEEnabled =Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Csv file with a "Hostname" column, like below, you can use `Import-Csv`.

Example servers.csv file:

```
Id,Hostname,"ServerRole"
123,Server1,"Web Server"
124,Server2,"Web Server"
131,Server3,"App Server"
132,Server4,"App Server"
```

Script using `foreach` and `Import-Csv` to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
# Clear the screen
Clear-Host

# Import the Hostname values from the CSV file
$ComputerNames = Import-Csv -Path "C:\servers.csv" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Hostname"

# Empty array to hold the results
$ResultSet = @()

# query each computer for their Page file and memory details
foreach($strComputer in $ComputerNames)
{
    $PageFile=Get-WmiObject Win32_PageFile -ComputerName $strComputer 
    $PFSize = ($PageFile.Filesize/(1024*1024))

    $colItems=Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -Namespace root\CIMv2 -ComputerName $strComputer 
    $total=0 
    foreach ($objItem in $colItems) {
        $total = $total + $objItem.Capacity 
    }

    $isPAEEnabled =Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer

    # Store all the details in a temporary hashtable
    $PageFileDetails = @{ 
        "ComputerName" = $strComputer
        "PagefileInMB" = $PFSize
        "Memory"       = $total
        "PAEEnabled"   = $isPAEEnabled
    }

    # Create a new object with the properties we defined in the hashtable and add it to the result
    $ResultSet += New-Object psobject -Property $PageFileDetails
}

# the host application will print out the details for each computer on the screen
$ResultSet
```

The `$ResultSet` variable now contains a `PSObject` representing each computer queried, each having a "ComputerName", "PagefileInMB", "Memory" and "PAEEnabled" property.

You can now easily find computer where say PAE is disabled:

```
$ResultSet | Where-Object {$_.PAEEnabled -eq $False}
```